# Intel Centrino Wireless N-2200 Latency Issues

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have the above wireless adapter (PCIE x1) and I've installed the latest drivers on a fresh Windows 7 Professional 64-bit OS. Motherboard is an AsRock Extreme3 Z87 and processor is i5 4670K. I am having problems with:

A) High latency. Using a work laptop, I am able to get a [speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net) ping of ~60ms and on the desktop with the above card the ping is 300-600ms. On my previous laptop, I could get uTorrent downloads to dump around 5-7Mb/s and I'm lucky to get 1.5Mb/s. I've tried the usual registry hacks to open up more congruent connections, but I still can't get this card to speed up.

B) This card apparently has Bluetooth connectivity built into it. I cannot seem to get the Bluetooth options to show up in the control panel.

Can anyone help me out? I'm beating my head against a brick wall and Google searches have not been lucrative.

Comment: Are you using the 2.4GHz bands or the 5 GHz bands? Is BT active (BT also uses the 2.4GHz band and will get in the way of WiFi).

Comment: Bluetooth is enabled in the properties section of the network card from the Control Panel, but I don't see a BT connection and the Bluetooth software that you normally see in Windows laptops doesn't appear either.

It's set to the 2.4Ghz bands, I have the Actiontec Verizon/Frontier Fios Router (not sure which revision) and truthfully I'm not sure if it supports 5Ghz.

Comment: Could you measure how strong the signal is at both the desktop and the laptop? (Use a tool like [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/)).

Comment: I'm not by my desktop now (at work), but Windows reported full strength at all times (not gaining/losing signal).